# Ollydbg equivalent for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, debugging, patch

is there any good equivalent debugger for Mac OS X?

Something that allows patching and saving of the assembly as well (with graphic interface?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

GDB is the gold standard for debugging on *nix.  GDB has all of the debugging features you would expect in a modern debugger.  For example, reverse debugging is the best feature to have if you are modifying the binary in memory,  when you make a mistake just step back and try again.    [DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) is a popular front end,  but seriously you should learn GDB's CLI.  It has bit of a learning curve,  but once you learn it you'll never go back.  Its a lot faster.

Saving a modified binary isn't that great of a feature.  Just open the binary with a hex editor like [Hex Fiend](http://ridiculousfish.com/hexfiend/) and modify it directly,  not a big deal.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a OSX person, but you might find [IDA](http://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml) useful, however, you will probably need to pay for the linux/osx versions, as there is only a free version for windows.

Comment: I am familiar with IDA but it's not such a good debugger. It doesn't have the ability to patch the code for example.

Comment: @DiGMi: IDA its self isn't a debugger, it just provides a UI for debuggers like Bochs or gdb. Also, IDA can do patching, at least at the hex level, you can also patch instruction operands.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the lldb debugger (http://lldb.llvm.org/) and of course gdb is available.